# Inconsistence when MySQL cast Boolean as JSON

Tags: mysql

Look at these two statements:

```
SELECT CAST(True AS JSON) -> true

SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN True ELSE False END AS JSON) -> 1
```

I got these results in MySQL 5.7.24.

Why different result has been given?

If the first is correct, what's the problem with the second? Vice versa.

Comment: `true` in JSON is **NOT** the same as `TRUE` in MySQL !!! In JSON this is pre-defined boolean constant. In MySQL this is an alias of `1` (the datatype is context-dependent, generic datatype is BIGINT). Check output for ```SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN True ELSE False END```..

Comment: @Akina that makes sense, but I don't understand what makes the two statements different. Are you saying that `CASE WHEN` is returning `1` instead of `True` (since it's an alias) while in the first case it actually returns `True` (since it's not an evaluation)?

Comment: In my opinion, it is impossible to understand. Just remember...

Comment: @Akina lmao, fair enough. thanks :p

Comment: Or you may think that "implicit convertion is performed only when it is needed according to the context". In 1st query this convertion not needed, hence CAST receives `true`. In 2nd query the result of whole CASE **must** be converted to some datatype during the intermediate result transferring from CASE to CAST, and alias is replaced with base value.